# Selected form options

Tags: php, forms

I currently have a form in which I can select a list of options from the database. I'm trying to get it to show the users selected option. It doesn't seem to be working.

```
<form action="include/validate.info.php" method="POST" target="ifr2">
Gender - <select name="gender">
<?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM settings_options WHERE option_type='gender'";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
while($option=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
if($option['option_value']==$user['gender']){
echo "<option value='".$option['option_value']."' selected='selected'>".$option['option_value']."</option>";                
}else{
echo "<option value='".$option['option_value']."'>".$option['option_value']."</option>";}} ?>  </select>
<input type="submit" value="save" class="settings_submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You did establish a link to your MySQL database earlier in the page, right?

Comment: I did. It just jumps back to the first option within the list.

Comment: Everything looks good here (although consider looking into [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)).  Have you confirmed that `$user['gender']` is being set properly?

Comment: if(isset($_POST['gender'])){
mysite_user_core::set_option("gender",$_POST['gender'],$_SESSION['id']);
}

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to add this to my page. FAIL $user = mysite_user_core::getuser($id);